# ActiveRecord 3 "IS IN" where queries

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, sinatra

What's the best way to do IS IN queries, especially when involving a join?

Currently, I have something like the following:

```
Table1.joins(:table2).where( { :table2s => { :ident => params[:idents].split(',') } } )
```

This works and gets the job done. The resulting WHERE clause is something like

```
WHERE "table2s"."ident" IS IN ('a','b','c')
```

I feel like this would be cleaner though:

```
Table1.joins(:table2).where("table2s.ident IS IN ?", params[:idents]:split(','))
```

Is there a way to avoid the first style and use something more like the second style? (i.e., the where method recognizes the array and uses IS IN rather than '=' operator)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Letting the query compiler do it for you is generally a better way to do it as it will handle cases you might forget, such as passing a `nil` value and ending up with an erroneous `IS IN(NULL)` instead of `IS NULL`. You can clean up your statement, though:

```
Table1.joins(:table2).where(:table2s => { :ident => params[:idents].split(',') })
```

Taking this a step further, you can reduce it to:

```
Table1.joins(:table2).where('table2s.ident' => params[:idents].split(','))
```

You could further clean this up by writing a scope that encapsulates this instead of using this as-is.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the split. ActiveRecord is smart enough to understand arrays, so all you need is `Table1.joins(:table2).where( { :table2s => { :ident => params[:idents]}})`.

In fact, you don't need the nesting. `Table1.joins(:table2).where('table2s.ident' => params[:idents])` should work find. Arel is pretty smart!

Comment: `params[:idents]` looks like a string, so he needs to `split`